# Remove first line from a Text block if it contains a specific string - using jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex, dom

I have a table that has some content in it. Not all rows has same content but some of them will have the first sentence as e.g.

> Hello, how are you John?
>
> Hello, how are you Mary?

Same pattern with different name.

The row will look like below. And the content in the span comes from database. Yes the text with break tags as well.

```
<tr style="background-color:#F7F7f7">
<td>
<span id="sp1">Hello How Are you? John <br/><br/>Some text blalablalalbal <br/><br/>"You are Awesome" <br/><br/>----What can I do for you? <br/><br/></span><br />
<span id="sp2">XYZABCD</span><br />
<span id="sp3">12345669060 Some Loren ipsum</span><br />
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to remove the first sentence from the rows that has *Hello, how are you xyzname?*.

So I have the following code that works and does what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnCleanUp").click(function () {
                $("table tr td").each(function () {
                    var elem = $(this).find('span:contains("Hello How Are you?")');
                    var alltxts = elem.contents().filter(function () {
                        var retm = true;
                        var str = this.nodeValue;
                        if (str != null) {
                            var bstr = str.indexOf("Hello How Are you?");
                            $(this).nodeValue = "";
                            if (bstr >= 0) {
                                retm = false;
                            }
                        }
                        var ret = (this.nodeType == 3) && retm;
                        return ret;
                    });
                    elem.text("");
                    elem.html("<br/>");
                    $(alltxts).each(function () {
                        var hm = $(this);
                        elem.html(elem.html() + hm[0].nodeValue + "<br/><br/>");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the sample [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDx4x/).

**Question:**

Can I do this in a better way?

I want to simplify the above code block if possible, I mean logic-wise because I think it can be done in a better way given the potential of jquery.

I am open to do this in C# if that's a better way. Please provide sample code.

Comment: Consider moving this to (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @maerics: Correct, codereview is also a place to post this question but I feel this place is still relevant. I actually was going to post this question yesterday to get a solution but I found this weird way which I am not satisfied with. So I put my work here. I can simply remove my code and request the community to give me a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnCleanUp").click(function () {
            $("table tr td span").each(function () {
                var data = $(this).html();
                data = data.replace(/^Hello how are you\?.*?(<br ?\/?>){1,2}/i,'');
                $(this).html(data);

            });
        });
    });
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvYWX/1/) for demo

But i'm not really sure JavaScript is the best place to be doing this.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it out. I am open to do that on server-side if that's a better way to go. Can you provide sample code to do this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of that `$.each` loop:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnCleanUp").click(function() {
        var elm = $("table tr td").find('span:contains("Hello How Are you?")');
        var alltxts = elm.contents().filter(function() {
            var retm = true;
            var str = this.nodeValue;
            if (str != null) {
                var bstr = str.indexOf("Hello How Are you?");
                $(this).nodeValue = "";
                if (bstr >= 0) {
                    retm = false;
                }
            }
            var ret = (this.nodeType == 3) && retm;
            return ret;
        });
        elm.text("");
        elm.html("<br/>");
        $(alltxts).each(function() {
            var hm = $(this);
            elm.html(elm.html() + hm[0].nodeValue + "<br/><br/>");
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ZDx4x/12/

Comment: just removing that each behaves abnormally. I will have to then modify the rest of the logic.